# How to control unnumbered section titles

Tags: unnumbered-sections

Generally, able to write some conditional statement for the numbered sections by using the tag `\ifnum #2 =` (e.g., `1` is for `\section` command) which is inside in the tags `\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{`, is it possible to write the same type of conditions for unnumbered sections also?

And the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Number and Title\protect\marginpar{CN\&CT}}

This is for test. 

\section{H1 head\protect\marginpar{H1}}

This is for test. 

\subsection{H2 head\protect\marginpar{H2}}

This is for test. 

\section*{H1 head}\protect\marginpar{H1}

This is for test. 

\subsection*{H2 head}\protect\marginpar{H2}

\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image]

I am trying to create the Marginal tags by auto, where ever these headings comes in a document.

Comment: if there is no number what should be the condition? And yes, I think this requires a minimal example -- if only to save me the time to write the test document myself.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am trying to print the heading order as in marginal note, like, if the tag `\subsection{...}` exists, then the text `H2" will print in the margin, for this I need this requirement, please advise...

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean. Make a sensible minimal example.

Comment: IIRC, unnumbered sections use \@ssect instead of \@sect.

Comment: How should latex know that you want only the H1 and H2 in the marginpar?